# JSON parsing with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am trying to catch a JSON request from a web api. When i get the response in JSON format from the server, I receive it in NSData format and not in NSDictionnary. I inspired myself from this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course# (A RESTful class paragraph) in order to have free JSON parsing by changing the registered operation class of my client by AFJSONRequestOperation. However, it doesn't work, I still get the response in NSData format.

EDIT: Here's the complete error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x753aa00'
```

Here is the response of the server:

```
{"uid":"98545931","token":"98545931:176:ec0b862ba57fef88394950dd0cc41491"}
```

Does someone have an idea why it can't be parsed automatically?

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseurl];
//Here, we tell the AFHTTPClient that the server is responding to us in JSON format.
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

//Creating the dictionary containing the post parameters.
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"username", password, @"password", nil];


//AUTHENTIFICATION. Retrieving token and uid by POST method.
[client postPath:@"/auth" parameters:params
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);
    [responseField setText:text];
    self.jsonResponse = responseObject;

    //The NSJSONSerialization method to transform the NSData responseObject into a dictionnary does work
    self.jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];

    //This NSLog makes the app crash with an unrecognized selector sent error
    NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"uid"]);
}
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
             [responseField setText:[error localizedDescription]];
}];
```

Comment: Did you actually check the class of `responseObject`?

Comment: The complete error message would be helpful ...

Comment: Sorry, added complete error message. As for the class of responseObject, I checked with the isKindOfClass method and it is actually an NSData.

Comment: From the comment above the second assignment of `self.jsonResponse` it sounds like you already figured this out.  You need to transform the `NSData` to a dictionary with the `NSJSONSerialization` API.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a call to `setDefaultHeader:value:` to set the `Accept` header to `application/json`. Without this, the JSON operation class won't be used, which means falling back on `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, which uses the `responseData` as its `responseObject`.

Comment: Correct! Header is set and everything is running smoothly, and from Matt Thompson! Thanks for the library AFNetworking and good luck with the ongoing Heroku project.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the default Header Accept to `application/json` value with the `setDefaultHeader:value:`  in order to tell AFHTTPRequestOperation it is actually JSON we're getting in the callback.